# Why was David's happiness so important to the Mecha descendants?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, ai-artificial-intelligence

At the end of the movie [Artificial Intelligence: A.I](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), the young protagonist David is found by the Mecha after 2000 years encased in ice.

According to their representation of the blue fairie, there was no detail too small that David didn't store for them, yet they do everything in their power to fulfill his wishes - but why?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

David was of great historical interest to the future A.I.s, since he had actual memories of human beings, who are apparently long extinct by their time. Beyond that, he was actually *built by humans*, where they are undoubtedly built by other A.I.s. Studying him would help them understand their own past. They wanted to preserve him, and although they are not organic, seem to have a morality which prevents them from simply taking him apart or locking him in a cage.